# how to insert a call-back for ActiveRecord's save function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

let's say we have a model called Student and it has a string field "name". There is wired requirement from the customer that all the student's name should consist of upper case
letter. I think it's better to give the user the freedom to choose "upper" style input or "lower" style input and let the server side, in my case ROR to take this it consideration.

I guess it might be possible to add some hook function before a record be saved and in the hook
function onecan implement the "lower" to "upper" convertion logic. Yes, I just make a bold guess So if you know other way to solve my problem, please di
tell me your way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what would you do with a name such as "de Wit"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview